# Initialising object

Tags: java, arrays, object, initialization

Why would someone initialize an object = -1?

```
int index = -1;
```

we use this code to search for an object in an array.
eg.

```
for(int i = 0; i < bArrayList.size(); i++) {
  if ( bAcc == bArrayList.get(i).getANum() ) {
    index = i;
  }
}
```

Comment: -1 is somewhat the default value you return for the index if the object you search for in the list or array is not found. Since the indices are valid starting from 0 to [number of elements - 1], if -1 is returned, you know the element is not found.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is -1 a magic number? An anti-pattern? A code smell? Quotes and guidelines from authorities](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3031975/is-1-a-magic-number-an-anti-pattern-a-code-smell-quotes-and-guidelines-from)

Comment: Please do not call a primitive data type variable in java "object". This is misleading.

Answer (score 1):

With an `int` you can not set it to `null`.  People commonly use -1 to represent null or nothing found in return.  They do this because when you do loop through stuff it starts at 0 not 1.

For example, say you have a function to get the index of a certain item in an array.  If the array does not have what you are looking for, returning 0 represents index: 0 and you can not return null because it is an integer, so instead you would return -1.